# Is there a way for your Android application to detect a system-update?

Tags: android

I have an Android application that would ideally receive some kind of broadcast when the system keyboard has been updated (I recently saw the system keyboard being updated on its own so I wonder if this is possible first). A broadcast on system-update would also suffice. Is there a way for your Android application to detect a soft input keyboard or system update?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#ACTION_SESSION_UPDATED, see if this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'm yet to test this but will get back to you.